# Iterate through files from UNC path to Local Directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, robocopy, unc

Given a UNC and a local Directory how would I go about copying files from remove to local in a simple, recursive fashion.

eg: - This works currently and copies all files within MyDIR to MyDEST:

```
SET MyDIR="\\123.10.10.10\Logs\Files\Server12\Folder1"
SET MyDEST="C:\Users\Desktop\Logs\Files"
robocopy %MyDIR% %MyDEST% /MIR
```

The issue I'm running into is that within MyDIR, Server12 has multiple (usually 3) folders stored and within them are the files I need so some level of iteration would help.

So I could try a bit of manual work and

```
SET MyDIR1=.....Folder1"
SET MyDIR2=.....Folder2"
SET MyDIR3=.....Folder3"
```

...as needed
but I'd also have to

```
robocopy %MyDIR1% %MyDEST% /MIR
robocopy %MyDIR2% %MyDEST% /MIR
robocopy %MyDIR3% %MyDEST% /MIR
```

which is easy enough but is there a way to loop through a list or even better, a way to recurse through all of Server12's folders and copy over all files?

I was thinking of using Powershell but I'm just trying to throw something together for quick, occasional use. I'm willing to but not sure if I should go in that direction as I have a bit of experience in it but not much.

I was able to get some for loops working but had errors when trying to get this to work with UNC the paths ( as well as using the %CD% variable to list the a UNC directory ).

Comment: Use [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) to get the UNC path linked to a temporary drive, so you can use a `for` loop, then use [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) to clean it up...

Comment: What is the reason for not using, `Set "MyDIR=\\123.10.10.10\Logs\Files\Server12"`, then use `/E` or `/S` with [tag:robocopy]?

Comment: Why would you mirror 3 different server directories to the same local directory?  That will effectively only mirror the last server directory you run.

Comment: @avery_larry - I removed the /MIR switch and the above worked as you suggest.
- robocopy worked well except I didn't want to keep the directory structure. I only wanted the files.
- pushd wasn't working well for me, giving errors but int he end I went that route. Had to simplify it a bit to get it to work with net use then just removed my path when I changed it to pushd - Stil have a few issues but I think this is good enough to post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end copy worked for my needs but a problem with my local paths containing a dash (yes a '-' because my company uses OneDrive it's in the path) was making it difficult to get this working. I passed FORFILES my variable, which contained the dash (demonstrated below).

In the end I had to use a temp folder....

```
SET MyRootDIR="\\123.10.10.10\Logs\Files\Server12"
SET MyDEST="C:\Users\Desktop\Logs - files\Files"
SET MyTempDEST="C:\LOGSTemp"

REM Delete these folders to empty them
DEL /Q %MyDEST%\*.*
DEL /Q %MyTempDEST%\*.*

PushD %MyRootDIR% &&(
    FORFILES /M *.* /S /C "cmd /c copy @file %MyTempDEST%"
     ) & PopD

MOVE %MyTempDEST%\*.* %MyRootDIR%
```

- I need the files only, because my next steps are to decompress the files and perform a keyword search within them outputting the results to a results.txt file.
- Variables are at top to make it easier to change to difference server instances.
- It works well but it has to be done in two steps. In PushD if I change it to to my variable %MyRootDIR% it gives me error :
  ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '-'.

Tried escaping etc with no luck but in the end the above works